# How copying elements without deleting originals?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, copy, appendchild

I have a loop to duplicate an array, and another to add copy in another div.
Both loop work good but original element are deleted, someone can explain me why?
And how can i fixe it? Thank you!

```js
var mesElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
var catchCopy = document.querySelector('.parent_copy');

var mesElementsCopie = []
for(var j = 0; j < mesElements.length; ++j){
    mesElementsCopie[j] = mesElements[j];
}
for(var k = 0; k < mesElements.length; ++k){
    catchCopy.appendChild(mesElementsCopie[k]);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_element" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="element">text</div>
    <div class="element">text</div>
    <div class="element">text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent_copy" style="background-color: green;"></div>
```

Comment: the original element is not deleted, you have just make it happened on another place in your DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line, you do not copy the node, but rather you create two references to the same DOM node:

```js
mesElementsCopie[j] = mesElements[j];
```

You should use the [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method:

```js
mesElementsCopie[j] = mesElements[j].cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: Thank you it works !

Answer (score 3):

Here's the fixed code:

```js
var mesElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
var catchCopy = document.querySelector('.parent_copy');

var mesElementsCopie = []
for(var j = 0; j < mesElements.length; ++j){
    mesElementsCopie[j] = mesElements[j].cloneNode(true);
}
for(var k = 0; k < mesElements.length; ++k){
    catchCopy.appendChild(mesElementsCopie[k]);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_element" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="element">text</div>
    <div class="element">text</div>
    <div class="element">text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent_copy" style="background-color: green;"></div>
```

You were adding the same elements you had grabbed from the parent element, so it was just moving them to the parent copy. Use `.cloneNode(true)` to make sure you're not using the same element.